# Are the triply-bonded carbons in pyridyne (and benzyne) sp-hybridised?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hybridization

I was given this molecule (3,4-pyridyne) in a test:

[image: 3,4-Pyridyne]

I had to find out if it had any atoms which had a hybridization state other than sp<sup>2</sup>. The solution said that it doesn't have any. But aren't the triply-bonded carbon atoms sp-hybridized?

Edit:
Benzyne also has a similar structure, with a distorted triple bond -

[image: Benzyne]

Comment: I also wanted to know what the IUPAC name of that compound would be. But I'm new to the site so I don't know if I should ask this as a new question, altogether. I don't see how that would be a good contribution to the site since it's only a picture.

Comment: This molecule does not exist, other than possibly as a short-lived intermediate. If not for this fact, your reasoning would be OK.

Comment: As for the name, 3,4-didehydropyridine would describe the structure well.

Comment: @IvanNeretin While equally thinking "if existing *at all*, than briefly only", May and Moody describe it as an easily obtained intermediate from shelf stable solid 3-(3,3-dimethyltriazen-l-yl)pyridine-4-carboxylic acid for moderately working Diels-Alder reactions with dienes like 2,5-dimethylfurane. (Tetrahedron Letters, 26, 1985, 2123-2124 "A convenient precursor to 3,4-didehydropyridine").

Comment: Related: [Why is the benzyne triple bond distorted?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/299/16683); [Structure of Benzyne](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38213/16683), although they don't directly address the issue of hybridisation head-on.

Comment: Thank you for the question, by the way; I learnt something, and apparently the conventional wisdom that the carbons are sp2 hybridised is not correct, which actually surprised me - I was expecting the calculations to output something intermediate between the idealised sp2 and sp hybridisation models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR It is sp-hybridised, but maybe not in the way we normally think of alkynes as being.**

---

There are a couple of things to say before going into the actual answer.

Firstly, hybridisation is derived from geometry, not from the bonding pattern (in other words, how many σ- and π-bonds there are). In most cases, the bonding pattern dictates the geometry: for example, most saturated carbons are tetrahedral, and a tetrahedral geometry usually signals sp<sup>3</sup> hybridisation, so saturated carbons are usually described as being sp<sup>3</sup>-hybridised. So, *effectively,* the bonding pattern does dictate hybridisation. This is all fine, but only up to a certain point, because it can break down in exceptional cases such as cyclopropane. Because of the geometrical constraints of a three-membered ring, there is not quite enough room for the carbon to be perfectly tetrahedral, and so it is not correct to label the carbons as being sp<sup>3</sup>-hybridised in the usual sense.

Secondly, hybridisation is usually more nuanced than "sp", "sp<sup>2</sup>" or "sp<sup>3</sup>". It is individual orbitals that are hybridised, not atoms; so for example, we can talk about an sp orbital, which is a linear combination (a sum) of one part s-orbital and one part p-orbital. When we say that "a carbon atom is sp-hybridised", what we *really* mean is that the bonding of that carbon atom can be described using four valence orbitals: two sp-hybridised orbitals, and two unhybridised p-orbital. Likewise, an "sp<sup>2</sup> carbon atom" uses three sp<sup>2</sup>-hybridised orbitals and one unhybridised p-orbital; and an "sp<sup>3</sup> carbon atom" has four sp<sup>3</sup> orbitals.

Again, in the vast majority of cases, these three categories are sufficient to accurately classify all carbon atoms in a molecule. However, as you may guess, this breaks down in exceptional cases: cyclopropane is the most well-known example. Here, each carbon has two sp<sup>5</sup>(ish) orbitals and two sp<sup>2</sup>(ish) orbitals. It uses the sp<sup>5</sup> orbitals to form σ-bonds to the carbons next to it, and the sp<sup>2</sup> orbitals to form σ-bonds to the two hydrogens on it. *"How is it possible to have five p orbitals?"* sp<sup>5</sup> does not literally mean one s orbital and five p orbitals; it just means the ratio of s-orbital and p-orbital contribution to this particular hybrid orbital is 1:5.

---

With that out of the way, here is how **benzyne** works (PBE0/cc-pVTZ gas phase optimisation + NBO analysis). We're going to look at the orbitals that the triply bonded carbon (C1) uses for bonding to its neighbours (C2 and C6, see structure below):†

- One sp orbital (50.02% s, 49.75% p) for forming a σ-bond to C2;
- One p orbital (0.39% s, 99.38% p) for forming the π-bond to C2 in the plane of the molecule;
- One p orbital (0.00% s, 99.84% p) for forming the π-bond to C2 perpendicular to the plane of the molecule;
- One sp orbital (49.64% s, 50.17% p) for forming a σ-bond to C6.

On their own, the numbers don't tell you which direction the p-orbitals are pointing in, but you can use visualisation software to figure this out. From left to right, these are the (σ- or π-, not the individual hybrid) orbitals, in the same order as listed above.

[image: NBO orbitals in benzyne, visualisation with Chemcraft]

Based on the above, the orbitals can be crudely illustrated as such:

[image: NBO orbitals in benzyne, drawn in ChemDraw]

This is, in fact, pretty much what an organic chemist would describe as an "sp-hybridised carbon atom". **However,** it is not sp-hybridised in the same sense as an ordinary alkyne. In an ordinary alkyne, the σ-bond between the two triply bonded carbons comes from overlap of sp-orbitals. This is also the case here, but there is a distinction. In an ordinary alkyne, the sp-orbitals point directly towards each other. Here, they are not quite aligned in the same way; they instead form what is sometimes called a "bent bond". The same can be said of the C1–C2 π-bond.

This is fundamentally because of the geometry of the ring. Since we have already allocated two p-orbitals to two other bonds, the two sp-orbitals must be derived from the same p-orbital. As a consequence, the two sp-orbitals must point in diametrically opposite directions, 180° away from each other. If C1 were to use an sp-orbital pointing directly towards C2, then the remaining sp-orbital would point rather far away from C6, significantly weakening the corresponding bond with C6. The orbital geometry that you see is a compromise.

The triply bonded carbons in **pyridyne**, for all intents and purposes, can be described in the same way as those in benzyne. The effect of nitrogen on the orbitals above is tiny; qualitatively they look the same (the colours are flipped for the first and last ones relative to the benzyne orbitals earlier, but this is of [no](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/85589/16683) [physical](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35212/16683) [significance](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/67344/16683)).

[image: NBO orbitals of 3,4-pyridyne, visualisation in Chemcraft]

---

† The numbers don't add up to exactly 100% because the tiny d- and f-orbital contributions are neglected.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Hybridization derives from geometry, not bond type.  For instance, the central carbon in allene ($\ce{CH2=C=CH2}$) has $sp$ hybridization like the carbons in acetylene, despite the absence of triple bonds in the allene, because the linear bonding geometry brings this hybridization about.

In pyridyne the formally triple-bonded carbons do not have the linear bonding geometry corresponding to $sp$  hybridization, rather the geometry corresponds to $sp^2$ hybridization like pyridine or benzene.  What seems to be one of the "pi" bonds in the pyridyne structure as drawn on paper, is in fact a "bent bond" formed by the side-by-side overlap of two subsidized orbitals, not a pi bond formed from two $p$ orbitals.

Comment: On the same note, this was another compound on the test (which _didn't_ have all sp$^2$ hybridized carbon, interestingly)
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114896/what-is-the-hybridization-state-of-carbons-in-10annulene.